# lz4 compression c++ example

Tags: c++, compression

In the process of writing a [lz4](http://code.google.com/p/lz4/) csv to compressed binary file converter (high volume forex tick data csv) in the hope of reducing the storage/disk bandwidth requirements on my tiny vps.
self contained code to illustrate

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "lz4.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char szString[] = "2013-01-07 00:00:04,0.98644,0.98676 2013-01-07 00:01:19,0.98654,0.98676 2013-01-07 00:01:38,0.98644,0.98696";
const char* pchSource = szString;
int nInputSize = sizeof(szString);

cout <<"- pchSource -" << endl << pchSource << endl;
cout <<"nbytes = "<< nInputSize << endl << endl;
ofstream source("pchSource.txt");
source << pchSource;

int nbytesPassed = 0;
int nMaxCompressedSize = LZ4_compressBound(nInputSize);

char *pszDest = new char[nMaxCompressedSize];
nbytesPassed = LZ4_compress(pchSource, pszDest, nInputSize);
cout <<"- pszDest Compressed-" << endl;
cout <<"nbytesPassed = "<< nbytesPassed << endl;
cout << pszDest << endl << endl;
// pszDest garbage ?

char *pszDestUnCompressed = new char[nInputSize];
LZ4_uncompress(pszDest, pszDestUnCompressed, nInputSize);
cout <<"- pszDestUnCompressed -" << endl;
cout <<"nbytesPassed = "<< nbytesPassed << endl;
cout << pszDestUnCompressed << endl << endl;
//pszDestUnCompressed is correct ?

delete[] pszDestUnCompressed;
pszDestUnCompressed = 0;

// ok lets write compressed pszDest to pszDest.dat
ofstream outCompressedFile("pszDest.dat",std::ofstream::binary);
outCompressedFile.write (pszDest,nMaxCompressedSize);

delete[] pszDest;
pszDest = 0;

//read it back in and try to uncompress it
ifstream infile("pszDest.dat",std::ifstream::binary);
infile.seekg (0,infile.end);
int nCompressedInputSize = infile.tellg();
infile.seekg (0);

char* buffer = new char[nCompressedInputSize];
infile.read (buffer,nCompressedInputSize);
const char* pchbuffer = buffer;

char* pszUnCompressedFile = new char[nInputSize];
nbytesPassed = LZ4_uncompress(pchbuffer, pszUnCompressedFile, nInputSize);
cout <<"- pszUnCompressedFile -" << endl;
cout <<"nbytesPassed = "<< nbytesPassed << endl;
cout << pszUnCompressedFile << endl;

//write uncompressed pszDest.dat to pszUnCompressedFile.txt
ofstream outUncompressedSource("pszUnCompressedFile.txt");
outUncompressedSource << pszUnCompressedFile;
// On my system 32bit ArchLinux 3.7.10-1 - gcc 4.7.2-4
// file contains random Garbage

delete[] buffer;
buffer = 0;

delete[] pszUnCompressedFile;
pszUnCompressedFile = 0;

return 0;
}


CONSOLE OUTPUT :
- pchSource -
2013-01-07 00:00:04,0.98644 .....
nbytes = 108

- pszDest Compressed-
nbytesPassed = 63
�2013-01-07 00:

- pszDestUnCompressed -
nbytesPassed = 63
2013-01-07 00:00:04,0.98644 .....

- pszUnCompressedFile -
nbytesPassed = -17
�W��W�-07 q

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.010 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

I'm obviously missing something, apart form the samples included in the source are there any-other usage examples ?

Answer (score 11):

All working now thanks, here is the code for anyone that is interested

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include "lz4.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char szSource[] = "2013-01-07 00:00:04,0.98644,0.98676 2013-01-07 00:01:19,0.98654,0.98676 2013-01-07 00:01:38,0.98644,0.98696";
int nInputSize = sizeof(szSource);

// compress szSource into pchCompressed
char* pchCompressed = new char[nInputSize];
int nCompressedSize = LZ4_compress((const char *)(&szSource), pchCompressed, nInputSize);

// write pachCompressed to binary lz4.dat
ofstream outBinaryFile("lz4.dat",ofstream::binary);
outBinaryFile.write(pchCompressed, nCompressedSize);
outBinaryFile.close();
delete[] pchCompressed;
pchCompressed = 0;

//read compressed binary file (assume we pass/encode nInputSize but don't know nCompressedSize)
ifstream infCompressedBinaryFile( "lz4.dat", ifstream::binary );

//Get compressed file size for buffer
infCompressedBinaryFile.seekg (0,infCompressedBinaryFile.end);
int nCompressedInputSize = infCompressedBinaryFile.tellg();
infCompressedBinaryFile.clear();
infCompressedBinaryFile.seekg(0,ios::beg);

//Read file into buffer
char* pchCompressedInput = new char[nCompressedInputSize];
infCompressedBinaryFile.read(pchCompressedInput,nCompressedSize);
infCompressedBinaryFile.close();

// Decompress buffer
char* pchDeCompressed = new char[nInputSize]; //(nCompressedInputSize *2) +8
LZ4_uncompress(pchCompressedInput, pchDeCompressed, nInputSize);
delete[] pchCompressedInput;
pchCompressedInput = 0;

// write decompressed pachUnCompressed to
ofstream outFile("lz4.txt");
outFile.write(pchDeCompressed, nInputSize);
outFile.close();

delete[] pchDeCompressed;
pchDeCompressed = 0;

return 0;
}
```

I am also working on a a simple CLI csv to binary I/O example [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/lz4c/nxGxhaXtjSI)

Comment: @swaybee comments, "Just a heads up if anyone is using the sample above; Apparently LZ4_uncompress()is now deprecated but you can call LZ4_decompress_fast() function with the exact same syntax. Just replace the name of the function and it should work (I'm using code release: 120)."

Comment: Thanks for the heads up saved me some time churning to new version.

Comment: LZ4_decompress_fast() is now deprecated also. Use LZ4_decompress_safe() instead